# Pass parameters from a project to a specific class in another project

Tags: c#, .net

I just started to learn C# for a school project but I'm stuck on something.

I have a solution with 2 projects (and each project has a class), something like this:

Solution:

- Server (project) (...) MyServerClass.cs, Program.cs
- App (project) (...) MyAppClass.cs, Program.cs

In my "MyServerClass.cs", I have this:

```
class MyServerClass
{
    ...
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        Process.Start("App.exe", "MyAppClass");
    }
}
```

How can I properly send, for example, an IP address and port? Would something like this work?

```
class MyServerClass
{
    ....
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        string ip = "127.0.0.1";
        int port = 8888;
        Process.Start("App.exe", "MyAppClass " + ip + " " + port);
    }
}
```

Then in my "MyAppClass.cs", how can I receive that IP address and port?

**EDIT:**

The objective of this work is to practice processes/threads/sockets. The idea is having a server that receives emails and filter them, to know if they're spam or not. We got to have 4 or 5 filters. The idea was having them as separated projects (ex: Filter1.exe, Filter2.exe, ...), but I was trying to have only 1 project (ex: Filters.exe) and have the filters as classes (Filter1.cs, Filter2.cs, ...), and then create a new process for each different filter.

I guess I'll stick to a project for each filter!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have to run them as two separate processes?

Comment: [**`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks @VisualVincent, that wasn't what I was looking for, but I'm going to use it (check my updated question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve this, each with their own pros/cons.

Some possible solutions:

- **Pass the values in on the command line**. Pros: Easy. Cons: Can only be passed in once on launch. Unidirectional (child process can't send info back). Doesn't scale well for complex structured data.
- **Create a webservice** (either in the server or client). Connect to it and either pull/push the appropriate settings. Pros: Flexible, ongoing, potentially bi-directional with some form of polling and works if client/server are on different hosts. Cons: A little bit more complex, requires one app to be able to locate the web address of the other which is trivial locally and more involved over a network.
- **Use shared memory via a memory mapped file**. This approach allows multiple processes to access the same chunk of memory. One process can write the required data and the others can read it. Pros: Efficient, bi-directional, can be disk-backed to persist state through restarts. Cons: Requires pointers and an understanding of how they work. Requires a little more manipulation of data to perform a read/write.

There are dozens more ways. Without knowing your situation in detail, it's hard to recommend one over another.

#### Edit Re: Updated requirements

Ok, command line is definitely a good choice here. A quick detour into some architecture...

There's no reason you can't do this with a single project.

First up, use an interface to make sure all your filters are interchangeable. Something like this...

```
public interface IFilter {
    FilterResult Filter(string email);
    void SetConfig(string config);
}
```

`SetConfig()` is optional but potentially useful to reconfigure a filter without a recompile.

You also need to decide what your IFilter's `FilterResult` is going to be. Is it a pass/fail? Or a score? Maybe some flags and other metrics.

If you wanted to do multiple projects, you'd put that interface in a "shared" or "common" project on its own and reference it from every other project. This also makes it easy for third parties to develop a filter.

Anyway, next up. Let's look at how the filter is hosted. You want something that's going to listen on the network but that's not the responsibility of the filter itself, so we need a network client. What you use here is up to you. WCF in one flavour or another seems to be a prime candidate. Your network client class should take in its constructor a network port to listen on and an instance of the filter...

```
public class NetworkClient {
    private string endpoint;
    private IFilter filter;
    public NetworkClient(string Endpoint, IFilter Filter) {
        this.filter = Filter;
        this.endpoint = Endpoint;
        this.Setup();
    }
    
    void Setup() {
        // Set up your network client to listen on endpoint.
        // When it receives a message, pass it to filter.Filter(msg);
    }
}
```

Finally, we need an application to host everything. It's up to you whether you go for a console app or winforms/wpf. Depends if you want the process to have a GUI. If it's running as a service, the UI won't be visible on a user desktop anyway.

So, we'll have a process that takes the endpoint for the NetworkClient to listen on, a class name for the filter to use, and (optionally) a configuration string to be passed in to the filter before first use.

So, in your app's `Main()`, do something like this...

```
static void Main() {
    try {
        const string usage = "Usage: Filter.exe Endpoint FilterType [Config]";
        var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        Type filterType;
        IFilter filter;
        string endpoint;
        string config = null;
        NetworkClient networkClient;
        switch (args.Length) {
            case 0:
                throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("{0}. An endpoint and filter type are required", usage));
            case 1:
                throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("{0}. A filter type is required", usage));
            case 2:
                // We've been given an endpoint and type
                break;
            case 3:
                // We've been given an endpoint, type and config.
                config = args[3];
                break;
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("{0}. Max three parameters supported. If your config contains spaces, ensure you are quoting/escaping as required.", usage));
        }

        endpoint = args[1];
        filterType = Type.GetType(args[2]); //Look at the overloads here to control where you're searching

        // Now actually create an instance of the filter
        filter = (IFilter)Activator.CreateInstance(filterType);
        if (config != null) {
            // If required, set config
            filter.SetConfig(config);
        }

        // Make a new NetworkClient and tell it where to listen and what to host.
        networkClient = new NetworkClient(endpoint, filter);

        // In a console, loop here until shutdown is requested, however you've implemented that.
        // In winforms, the main UI loop will keep you alive.

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString()); // Or display a dialog
    }

}
```

You should then be able to invoke your process like this...

```
Filter.exe "127.0.0.1:8000" MyNamespace.MyFilterClass
```

or

```
Filter.exe "127.0.0.1:8000" MyNamespace.MyFilterClass "dictionary=en-gb;cutoff=0.5"
```

Of course, you can use a helper class to convert the config string into something your filter can use (like a dictionary).

When the network client gets a `FilterResult` back from the filter, it can pass the data back to the server / act accordingly.

I'd also suggest [a little reading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn223671(v=pandp.30).aspx) on Dependency Injection / Inversion of control and Unity. It makes a pluggable architecture much, much simpler. Instead of instantiating everything manually and tracking concrete instances, you can just do something like...

```
container.Resolve<IFilter>(filterType);
```

And the container will make sure that you get the appropriate instance for your thread/context.

Hope that helps

Comment: No worries. I've added a possible architecture to get you started. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Basic! Some parts of what you provided are still a bit too advanced to my knowledge, but I'm gonna do some research on them and try to implement it :)

Comment: @AndréBotelho If you get stuck with anything, let me know and I'll see if I can find you a good link.